# Is the acceleration of the expansion of the universe a direct observation or an interpretation?

Tags: universe, supernova, expansion, observable-universe

Is the acceleration of expansion we observe with supernovae direct or is this an interpretation according $\Lambda$CDM model ?

I mean what we observe is luminosity distance versus redshift, so to see acceleration we should have scale factor vs time, which need a model, right (assuming Friendmann-Lemaître equations in which we need to consider homogenous universe for example) ?

Is it possible to say "our universe is in accelerated expansion" without any  interpretation with a model ?

Comment: Supernova brightness vs redshift.

Comment: Redshift of line emission